# Why are almost all bicycle tyres cross-ply/bias ply and not radial construction?

Tags: tire, technology

Most times when I see a failed bicycle tyre (one where the threads are showing through) they look something like this, with diagonal threads clearly visible

[image: https://media.wired.com/photos/593331eb4cd5ce6f96c0c96d/master/pass/retired.jpeg]

Here's a random manufacturer's cutaway showing diagonal casing threads
[image]

Here's a line diagram showing the difference:
[image: http://cdn1.bikebandit-images.com/blog/images/2016/bias-ply-vs-radial-tires/bias-ply-vs-radial-4.png]

So I'd reason that most/all bicycle tires are Cross Ply in build, and not Radial.

My google-fu does return these points:

- Radial tyres are cheaper to make than the equivalent cross ply
- Radial tyres are lighter and have better fuel economy than a cross ply
- Radial tyres track better, where cross ply tyres have been known to "tramline" vehicles.
- Cross ply tyres have a more rigid sidewall, radial tyres have a more supple sidewall.
- Suspension needs to be altered in a car to accommodate the differences between ride handling in the two styles.

Usage

- Automobiles tyres are almost exclusively radial.
- 4WD tyres are predominantly radial, but cross ply have much better sidewall strength and resist damage better.
- Motorcycle tyres may be either, where radials are preferred for speed and cross ply are preferred for load carrying (touring or cruising)
- Truck (ie load carrying vehicles) might use either, with cross ply for load carrying and radial for long distance.

Even [wikipedia is ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_tire#Application), saying

> Radial tires have occasionally found application on bicycles, used on the 1980s Miyata touring bicycle; models 1000 and 610,[19] and more recently in 2009 on the Maxxis Radiale.[20] Panaracer radial tires were also standard on the Jamis Gentry model bicycle in 1985.

I would have expected that radial construction with "supple side walls" to help a lot in reducing rolling resistance, but its uncommon.

Why are Radial tyre constructions uncommon in bicycle tyres?

Comment: I would expect that radial tires would not survive as long -- the sidewalls would tend to deteriorate and split vertically.

Comment: Quoting Sheldon (I don't personally know, taking his word for it): "Radial tires have been tried for bicycles, but they tend to be too floppy from side to side. This floppiness feels quite unpleasant in actual riding--much like the feel of a grossly underinflated tire."  https://sheldonbrown.com/tires.html

Comment: More recently there was a radial racing tire from Schwalbe. They were first recalled then quietly dropped from product line. Recall news is still online: http://www.bikeradar.com/news/article/schwalbe-issues-warning-about-ultremo-r-tyres-21793/

Comment: Some time ago I was wondering about the same question and did some digging online, turned out that Panaracer Radiale wasn't a true radial but had a bias ply layer to reduce floppiness. They had a reputation for delamination, too. I'm wondering why radial tires always fail on bicycles when they are successful everywhere else.

Comment: I imagine for similar reasons that we generally don't use radial laced wheels for wheels that handle any loads.

Comment: @ojs: "everywhere else", which is basically motor vehicles, is considerably less weight sensitive.

Comment: There's a huge market for bike tires that weight two to four times a lightweight racing tire. I wouldn't call it weight sensitive. Can you explain why a radial tire would be heavier?

Comment: Bicycle tyres need stiffer sidewalls. Soft sidewalls will alter the geometry of the system when leaning into a turn and modify the behaviour of the cycle in a turn. Motorcycle radials are wider than their height (around 100/50) which lessens the squashing. Bicycle have an tyres almost circular section..

Comment: @ojs my company sells Maxxis, and the same thing happened with the first run of the Radiale.  Now we only seem to carry the Tubeless version, and they don't sell very well.

Comment: Oops, I mixed Panaracer and Maxxis. The few who have had Panaracers seem to have good memories of them.

Comment: @Carel thanks, that probably explains things.

Comment: @ojs - I don't think they were radials, but I decided to avoid Panaracers about 25 years ago, because the sidewalls were always splitting.

Comment: @ojs I actually had a pair of those radial Schwalbe tires (Ultremo) that were recalled. I remember it being a fast tire but that they suddenly developed lumps within a few hundred km.  Perhaps the higher pressures associated with bike tires does not work well with radial builds? That said, hoop stress is also less on a bike tire, so Carel's comment seems sensible too.

Comment: I'm not so sure about pressure. Bus and heavy truck tires are inflated up to 9 bar and they are radial. But yes, those tires have steel belts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the biggest factor influencing bicycle tires has to do with the 4th bullet point you mentioned, sidewall stiffness, combined with using inner tubes instead of just being a pneumatic tire.  Cross-ply tires with their more rigid sidewall would be less prone to snakebite punctures of tubes and would hold rims off the ground with less pressure.  Radials would have more of a propensity for the sidewall to collapse with low pressures.

Comment: Sidewall collapse is not just a problem because of the potential of snake bites, but also to keeping track in curves. When you lean into a curve, the inner sidewall is unloaded, and if it collapses, the wheel crawls away out of the curve. This is a really nasty feeling, if not downright dangerous. I had such a tire exactly once in my live, and I tell you, I'll never ride that tire's brand again.

Answer (score 12):

Radial bicycle tires are very rare. The reason is that the lateral stiffness is much lower than for cross-ply tires. Imagine that you press the sidewall of a tire by your thumb. With a cross-ply casing the cords on which you apply pressure are anchored to the bead wires over a distance of about twice the tire width and the whole section shares resistance to deformation. In case of a radial tire the cords run in the same direction as the force, hence offer very limited resistance. Radial tires are prone to squirming and unstable cornering.

Yet a few manufactures still offer radial tires. I know of the Vittoria Diamante Pro Radiale 700x22 for road bikes <s>and the CST Sensamo Speed 35-622 for touring bikes</s>.
The riding experience with the Vittoria tires, published on https://cycletechreview.com/2012/reviews/vittoria-diamante-pro-radiale-tyre-review/  , suggest that they might please persevering afficionado's.
It is probably not accidental that the width is limited to 22 mm. The bigger the diameter, the softer the structure get and, probably, the higher the inflation pressure required for stable load carrying (limited load carrying might be the explanation why airplanes and heavy trucks don't use radial tires but cross-ply tires).

In his study of tire properties, Andrew Dressel included a Maxxis prototype 22-622 tire. He reports (page 113)  'The Maxxis prototype, which is described as “radial” and does appear to have cords aligned at about 22.5º, instead of the 45º usually associated with bias-ply, does not have stiffnesses noticeably different from other tires of similar size.' Here the small width combined with the in-between design would explain the results. See  https://dc.uwm.edu/etd/386/

Comment: Interesting - great first answer.  One might have thought low-pressure MTB tyres would benefit from softer sidewalls, but perhaps other factors outweigh that advantage.

Comment: I was looking for a radial tire and I actually contacted CST, and their R&D dept confirmed that the Sensamo Speed is not radial ply tire, and they do not make any for bikes at the moment